# Update Query Error using php

Tags: php

hi to all m using the following query:

```
$rows = mysql_query("UPDATE admin SET create ='".$close."' WHERE id=".$id) or die(mysql_error());
```

but i got the following error:
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create ='0' WHERE id=6' at line 1**

help me plz in this regard thnx in advance

Comment: @KA_lin Don't you mean BEGIN it...

Answer (score 8):

`create` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). You'll have to escape it:

```
UPDATE admin SET `create`=...
                 ^-     ^-
```

Comment: i have change the query $rows = mysql_query("UPDATE admin SET 'create' ='".$close."' WHERE id=".$id) or die(mysql_error());
but the error is same

Comment: wrong quotes. use backticks: `  . normal quotes, `'` turn things into strings.

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote your query correctly with backticks (`` ` ``) as `create` is a reserved keyword in MySQL.

```
$rows = mysql_query("UPDATE admin SET `create` = '".$close."' WHERE `id` = ".$id) or die(mysql_error());
```

I highly recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo.php).

Comment: `id` doesn't need to be quoted. it's not a reserved word.

Comment: True but it's consistent. I would always use PDO anyway.

Comment: Actually, yes you are right. I was thinking of ORM behaviour! Still PDO is the way forward.

Comment: i have change the query $rows = mysql_query("UPDATE admin SET 'create' ='".$close."' WHERE id=".$id) or die(mysql_error());
but the error is same

Comment: You are using the wrong type of quoting. You should be using backticks `. Copy my code posted in the answer.

Comment: @MATT reall thanks sir..m soo happy. but i want to request to you please suggest me the link where there is a list of reserved words in php